# addPostFrameCallback vs scheduleFrameCallback

Tags: flutter, flutter-state

So, I was wondering, when to use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` and `WidgetsBinding.instance.scheduleFrameCallback` for `setState`, as according to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html), the first one doesn't initiate a frame on its own, while if we asynchronously call `setState` then it might get called during the build of another widget, which can cause not to update the other widget, so for it, we add it as a "post frame" callback, but if it is called not during a build, then it will not initiate the next frame on its own, i.e we cannot always wrap async `setState` calls with it, as there is a good chance it might be called during not a build, that's when I found `scheduleFrameCallback`, and according to its [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/scheduleFrameCallback.html), I think it schedules the next frame and adds its as a callback to it, i.e it also initiates a frame. So is it always better to call `setState` inside it, or is it something else?